# Google Ngram sorting?

Tags: node.js, sorting, n-gram

From what I understand, each file in [Google's Ngram dataset](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) contains a list of ngrams, sorted alphabetically, then numerically by year. However, assuming the data is UTF8 (which `file` says is correct), `и` is 1080, where `I` is 73, so I don't understand why `использовал_NUM` comes before `I'Academie_PRON`. The relevant lines from the file (starting from line #131356):

```
использовал_NUM 2005    4       1
I'Academie_PRON 1813    1       1
```

Here's my [ngram-sort-test.js](https://gist.github.com/beardtree/6025521#file-gistfile1-js-L24-L38) with the broken comparison function highlighted. To run, download [this file from Google](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-i.gz) and un-gzip it in the same directory as ngram-sort-test.js.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but my workaround was to manually sort the file using `LC_ALL=C sort <googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-i >googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-i.sorted`.